# equals() without hashCode()

Tags: java, hash, hashcode

Can I only implement equals() but not hashCode() if I only need to compare objects and not yet plan to put the objects into any hash based containers?

Seems all Java bibles say these two MUST be implemented together. :(

My concerns:
-If I always implement hashCode() together with equals() there will be lots of code not really used, and without unit test covering. (I'm not going to unit test hashCode() if not used)
-It's only until when I put the object into a hash based container I know how the objects are intended to be looked up. And only until then I can be sure which hashing strategy to use.

Comment: ref your concern: You might want to look into automatic testing the equals/hashcode contract using https://github.com/jqno/equalsverifier

Comment: A simple way to make the code *conforming* to the Object specification is to return the same constant value from hashCode. This is not ideal (ie. bad collisions if ever used as a hash), but it will never 'fail' because the contract is upheld..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can, but you'll be breaking the [general contract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) of `equals`:

> If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.

... and this will lead to weird bugs. Even if you don't think you're using the hash codes, any external code you pass the objects to might rely on them, even if it doesn't seem to be hash-based. If you're not going to give your objects a decent hash method, at least make it throw a runtime exception. It's almost always better to give your objects a decent hashCode, though.

Answer (score 5):

Oracle's tutorial [answers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html) this

> **The hashCode() Method**
>
> By definition, if two objects are equal, their hash code must also be equal. If you override the equals() method, you change the way two objects are equated and Object's implementation of hashCode() is no longer valid. Therefore, if you override the equals() method, you must also override the hashCode() method as well.

Answer (score 4):

As long as is not mandatory to implement hashCode, **whenever you implement equals, you MUST also implement hashCode**

> If you fail to do so, you will end up with broken objects. Why? An object’s hashCode method must take the same fields into account as its equals method. By overriding the equals method, you’re declaring some objects as equal to other objects, but the original hashCode method treats all objects as different. So you will have equal objects with different hash codes. For example, calling contains() on a HashMap will return false, even though the object has been added.

Answer (score 2):

*Can I only implement equals() but not hashCode()?*

Yes You can . Because they are just to method from the parent class `Object`, So it actually your choice to implement or not to (together or individual.)

`All Java bibles say these two MUST be implemented together.`

If you are not using anything related to `hashcode`(as you said hash based container) it not a `MUST`, But it is a good practice to implement them together to avoid any unexpected circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, yes, you can only implement equals() method without implementing hashcode() method.

But that would be a [breach of contract](https://www.baeldung.com/java-equals-hashcode-contracts#2-equals-contract).

The standard practice says that you should implement both of them and for the equal object the hashcode should be the same.

Comment: This answer is picked up by google as the right one =D

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but is it recommended ? no

What all books say, is that if equals returns true, the hashcodes MUST be identical, which will be so. But, it is best to specify it further, for your own instances, just like you do with equals.

Answer (score 0):

Well, obviously You can, but the fact that You don't plan to use hashing is not a sufficient reason not to implement it. Some of the libraries You use could make use of hashing. If you want to avoid testing equals or hashcode, You could try auto-generating those methods (most IDEs have that feature), or use project lombok (https://projectlombok.org)