# Java 8 distinct() does not invoke the equals method

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

In Java 8, the docs for distinct() intermediate operation state

> Returns a stream consisting of the distinct elements (according to >Object.equals(Object)) of this stream. 
>   For ordered streams, the selection of distinct elements is stable (for duplicated elements, the element appearing first

But it is not getting called

Equals method in my Item Class

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    System.out.println(this.name+"<->"+((Item)obj).name);
    return this.name.equals(((Item)obj).name);
}
```

Defining Data in Data class

```
public static List<Item> getItemList(){     
    itemData.add(new Item("Orange","Citrus Fruit","Orange",30,true,false));
    itemData.add(new Item("Apple Green","Universal Fruit","Green",60,false,true));
    itemData.add(new Item("Papaya","Wonderful Fruit","Yellow",120,false,true));
    itemData.add(new Item("Papaya","Wonderful Fruit","Green",100,false,true));
    .
    .
    .
    itemData.add(new Item("Strawberry","Citrus Fruit","Red",25,true,false));
    itemData.add(new Item("Sapota","Brown Fruit","Brown",32,false,true));

    return itemData;
}
```

Using Streams

```
Data.getItemList().stream().distinct().forEach(System.out::println)
```

but i realize that the equals method is not called

Comment: Not sure if this answers your question, but just because you don't see `equals()` being called does not mean that the stream is not calling it internally, without you seeing it.

Comment: Please consider to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if possible. This way, it's more likely volunteers on SO can help you.

Comment: Are you sure `Data.getItemList().distinct()` compiles? AFAIK `java.util.List` doesn't have a method `distinct()`.

Comment: I agree with @Thomas, you do not appear to using a stream.

Comment: @Thomas i will edit. the distinct() is called on the stream which i skipped. Anyhow the result is still the same equals() is not called. I don't see console output for equals method

Comment: Did you also implement the `hashCode()` method in your class `Item` (consistent with the `equals` method you implemented)? Even though the docs don't say so, this is necessary for `distinct()`.

Comment: Yes i implemented and then it worked

Comment: @RaghaveShukla 
When you implement equals(), you must implement hashCode() too.
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30026097/equals-without-hashcode

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Beside `equals()`, you need to override `hashCode()` method as well. The `distinct()` method probably uses a set internally, which in turn require a properly implemented `hashCode()`. More [info](https://www.baeldung.com/java-equals-hashcode-contracts).

Comment: No documentation says that distinct can only work on sets. Anyhow if i am using Sets which by default store unique elements based on hashCode why do i even need distinct(). But still i will try

Comment: Anyhow the real problem is the equals method is not getting called

Comment: Oh Yes ! you are correct, equals method is only called when hashCode is matched

Comment: No it seems that it calls equals only when hashCode is matched. Just like the Hash based collections work

Answer (score 6):

Are you also overriding the HashCode method??

There is no overloading possible for `distinct`. If you want to provide custom logic for comparison then you are better of using the `distinctBy` API.

[DistinctBy](https://www.baeldung.com/java-streams-distinct-by)

Comment: I dont think so there is any overloading in question. The stream api docs for distinct() mention that distinct() uses equals method of the Steam element. But then it should be called.